Selenium JS code for extracting text from Tinymce editor
After uploading an image in https://ocr.sanskritdictionary.com/, the copyable text comes in a Tinymce editor. Could someone suggest how to copy the resulting text using Slenium Javascript webdriver code?
I tried to extract it using the html body id of the text, it did not work. I also tried this method suggested by Gemini, it did not work:
    // Wait for the Tinymce editor to appear (adjust the timeout as needed)
    const tinymceEditor = await driver.findElement(By.id(tinymceId));
    await driver.wait(
      () => tinymceEditor.isDisplayed(),
      60000 // Wait for up to 10 seconds
    );

    // Execute JavaScript to get the content from the Tinymce editor
    const text = await driver.executeScript(
      'return document.getElementById("' + tinymceId + '").innerHTML;',
      tinymceEditor
    );

Thanks for any suggestion

The problem is that TinyMCE wraps its content inside an iframe, and your current approach is trying to access the content directly through the element's innerHTML, which won’t work because the actual content is inside the iframe.
To get the content from a TinyMCE editor, you need to switch to the iframe that TinyMCE uses and then use the TinyMCE API to retrieve the content. Here's how you can do it:
// Wait for the TinyMCE editor to be ready
const tinymceEditor = await driver.findElement(By.id(tinymceId));
await driver.wait(() => tinymceEditor.isDisplayed(), 60000); // Wait up to 60 seconds

// Switch to the TinyMCE iframe
await driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.css('#' + tinymceId + '_ifr')));

// Get the content from the TinyMCE editor
const text = await driver.executeScript('return tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();');

// Switch back to the main document
await driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

console.log('TinyMCE content:', text);

What's happening here:

Switch to the iframe: TinyMCE puts its editor content inside an iframe, so we have to switch the Selenium context to that iframe first.
Get the content: tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(); is a TinyMCE API call that gives you the content inside the editor.
Switch back: After grabbing the content, switch back to the main document so you can continue interacting with other elements on the page.

This should give you the correct content from the TinyMCE editor.
